# How to apply backpressure with rsocket-go?

Tags: rsocket

I know I must be missing some basic here. I'm familiar with RX Request(n) semantics for backpressure, but I'm struggling to make it work with rsocket-go. What I tried was calling `DoOnNext` and then blocking inside that call, but rsocket appears to just continue buffering and filling up memory. How do I prevent it from receiving further messages until I've processed them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by following the test case [here](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-go/blob/473989b43c9524185babd293a088cad842e0061a/rx/flux/flux_test.go#L121).

Basically:

```golang
var su rx.Subscription

f.DoOnNext(func(input payload.Payload) error {
        su.Request(1)
        return nil
}).
Subscribe(context.Background(), rx.OnSubscribe(func(ctx context.Context, s rx.Subscription) {
        su = s
        su.Request(1)
}))
```